# How do I avoid calling my function multiple times when I'm calling it with multiple jQuery change() methods?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a **price label** that dynamically changes whenever the user changes the value of my **product dropdown**, **departure date** and **return date**. I call `getPrice()` whenever each of these 3 are changed.

My goal is to call getPrice() method only once but still compute the correct price based on the currently selected **product**, **departure date** and **return date**.

*Take note the getPrice() takes **dropdown**, **departure date** and **return date** as arguments.*

My code is basically like this:

EDITED -- I put a working code snippet that's similar to my code.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
getDeptFormat();
getRetFormat();

$("#dropdown").change(function () {
getDeptFormat();
getRetFormat();
getPrice();
});

$("#departureDate").change(function () {
getPrice();
});

$("#returnDate").change(function () {
getPrice();
});

$("#reset").click(function () {
$("#totalPrice").html('').append('0');
})

})


function getDeptFormat() {
    $("#departureDate").daterangepicker({    
        singleDatePicker: true, 
          "startDate":getDeptMinDate(),     
    });
}

function getRetFormat() {
    $("#returnDate").daterangepicker({    
        singleDatePicker: true,  
       "startDate":getRetMinDate(),     
    });
}

function getPrice() {
  $("#totalPrice").append("5");
}

function getDeptMinDate() {
    var add = "10/25/2019";
   
   if (parseInt($("#dropdown").val()) == 1)
   {
    add = "10/26/2019";
   }
   else if (parseInt($("#dropdown").val()) == 2)
   {
   add = "10/27/2019";
   }
   else if (parseInt($("#dropdown").val()) == 3)
   {
   add = "10/28/2019";
   }   
    return add;
}

function getRetMinDate() {
    var add = "10/26/2019";
   
   if (parseInt($("#dropdown").val()) == 1)
   {
    add = "10/27/2019";
   }
   else if (parseInt($("#dropdown").val()) == 2)
   {
   add = "10/28/2019";
   }
   else if (parseInt($("#dropdown").val()) == 3)
   {
   add = "10/29/2019";
   }   
    return add;
}
```

```css
#container {
  border: 1px solid red;
padding :20px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />


<div id="container">
 <select  id="dropdown">
                            <option value="1">Product 1</option>
                            <option value="2">Product 2</option>
                            <option value="3">Product 3</option>
                        </select>
 <input type="text"  id="departureDate" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" />
 <input type="text"  id="returnDate" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" />

<div>
Price:<span id="totalPrice">0</span></div>
<button type="button" id="reset">Click to reset price</button>

</div>
```

Notice that whenever I change the dropdown, the getPrice() function is being called 3 times. The getPrice() function is a bit slow that's why it is irritating when it is being called multiple times. What is the best way to call the getPrice() function only once but still compute it based on the currently selected dropdown, departure date and return date?

I'm currently trying to understand asynchronous javascript and promises for now because they might help me with my problem. I'm sorry if my question's a bit confusing.

Comment: Try to make a reproducible in JSFiddle for example, this will be easier to guess the answer.

Comment: Sorry! Noted on this, i will try to do just that! Thank you!

Comment: Try my answer @VictorZyonTiangson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use change event for date value change detection. Use datepicker callback function when date is being changed.

Ex. remove below code:

```
$("#departureDate").change(function () {
getPrice();
});
```

Use this code:

```
$("#departureDate").daterangepicker({    
        singleDatePicker: true, 
          "startDate":getDeptMinDate(),     
    }, function(start, end, label) {
        getPrice();
    });
```

Code pen link:
https://codepen.io/alfazjikani/pen/wvvPJeg

Reference:
https://www.daterangepicker.com/

Comment: Apologies for the late reply, I was on vacation. I tried this immediately and it worked like a charm! You sir just saved me 6 secs of loading time! From now on I'll study documentations properly before applying it.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the same event for multiple elements using [Multiple Selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/).

Please try with below updated code-

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  getDeptFormat();
  getRetFormat();

  $("#dropdown, #departureDate, #returnDate").change(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('id') == "dropdown") {
      getDeptFormat();
      getRetFormat();
    }
    getPrice();
  });

  $("#reset").click(function() {
    $("#totalPrice").html('').append('0');
  })

})


function getDeptFormat() {
  $("#departureDate").daterangepicker({
    singleDatePicker: true,
    "startDate": getDeptMinDate(),
  });
}

function getRetFormat() {
  $("#returnDate").daterangepicker({
    singleDatePicker: true,
    "startDate": getRetMinDate(),
  });
}

function getPrice() {
  $("#totalPrice").append("5");
}

function getDeptMinDate() {
  var add = "10/25/2019";

  if (parseInt($("#dropdown").val()) == 1) {
    add = "10/26/2019";
  } else if (parseInt($("#dropdown").val()) == 2) {
    add = "10/27/2019";
  } else if (parseInt($("#dropdown").val()) == 3) {
    add = "10/28/2019";
  }
  return add;
}

function getRetMinDate() {
  var add = "10/26/2019";

  if (parseInt($("#dropdown").val()) == 1) {
    add = "10/27/2019";
  } else if (parseInt($("#dropdown").val()) == 2) {
    add = "10/28/2019";
  } else if (parseInt($("#dropdown").val()) == 3) {
    add = "10/29/2019";
  }
  return add;
}
```

```css
#container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />


<div id="container">
  <select id="dropdown">
    <option value="1">Product 1</option>
    <option value="2">Product 2</option>
    <option value="3">Product 3</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" id="departureDate" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" />
  <input type="text" id="returnDate" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" />

  <div>
    Price:<span id="totalPrice">0</span></div>
  <button type="button" id="reset">Click to reset price</button>

</div>
```